# Do all Perl 6 quoting constructs have term precedence?

Tags: raku, operator-precedence

The `< >` has term precedence. Here's the [example from the docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Term_Precedence):

```
say <a b c>[1];
```

I figured the same precedence would apply to all of the quoting operators. This works:

```
my $string = '5+8i';
my $number = <<$string>>;
say $number;
```

This interpolates `$string` and creates allomorphes (in this case a [ComplexStr](https://docs.raku.org/type/ComplexStr)):

```
(5+8i)
```

But, if I try to index it like the example from the docs, it doesn't compile:

```
my $string = '5+8i';
my $number = <<$string>>[0];
say $number;
```

I'm not quite sure what Perl 6 thinks is happening here. Perhaps it's thinking it's a hyperoperator:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling ...
Cannot use variable $number in declaration to initialize itself
at /Users/brian/Desktop/scratch.pl:6
------>     say $⏏number;
    expecting any of:
        statement end
        statement modifier
        statement modifier loop
    term
```

I can skip the variable:

```
my $string = '5+8i';
say <<$string>>[0];
```

But that's a different error that can't find the closing quotes:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling ...
Unable to parse expression in shell-quote words; couldn't find final '>>'
at /Users/brian/Desktop/scratch.pl:8
------> <BOL>⏏<EOL>
    expecting any of:
        statement end
        statement modifier
        statement modifier loop
```

Comment: another datapoint: `<<"$string">>[0]` works as expected

Comment: Indeed.  The `"` are just another way to prevent the parser to get into the `>>.` cul-de-sac.

Answer (score 7):

I think this warrants a rakudobug email.  I think the parser gets confused trying to interpret it as a `hyper` (aka `>>.method`).  The following workaround seems to corroborate this:

```
my $string = '5+8i';
my $number = <<$string >>[0];  # note space before >>
say $number;
```

To satisfy your OCD, you could probably also put a space before `$string`.

And yes, whitespace is not meaningless in Perl 6.

Answer (score 7):

Jonathan has the answer in response to [RT #131695](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=131695).

The `>>[]` is a [postfix operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#postfix_%C2%BB._/_postfix_>>.) to index a list, so it tries to use it as such. This is intended behavior. Fair enough, although I think the parser is being a bit too clever for regular code monkeys here.

Comment: The parser is not being clever so much as being very literal-minded. At some point the rule for qq interpolation of variables turned into something very much like "interpolate any sigilled variable, plus any postfix operators that might follow, terminated by a postcircumfix". Convenient when you want to do "$foo.uc()" or whatever. But also a source of thinkos. This bites me most often in HTML strings like "$stuff<tag>...</tag>", where the "<tag> part ends up being parsed as a postcircumfix.